# How to find $ \lim _{x\to \infty }\left\{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}\right\} $ where $\{x\}=x-[x] =$ fractional part?

Tags: limits, radicals, fractional-part

$$
\lim _{x\to \infty }\left\{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}\right\}   
$$

where $\{x\}=x-[x] =$ fractional part

---

I've got not determination case infinit - infinit and don't know what other route to take

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: What kind of value is $x$ here?  Is it an integer?  A real value?

Comment: It might be useful to note that
$$
\sqrt{x^2 + x + 1} - x = \frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^2 + x + 1} + x} \to \frac 12
$$

Comment: I've tried forced common factor and this radical was infinity and int part of it also infinity, and it was infinity-infinity which is indetermination.

x is from Z

Comment: @AndreeaMika okay.  In the future, you should include information like that (a quick description of what you tried) in the comments.  Otherwise, your question is likely to be closed.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom and what you have written isn't a different limit? I saw you used conjugation but it isn't the same case for the one I wrote.

Comment: @AndreeaMika It is.  As you'll notice, my comment doesn't say "the answer is...".  Instead, it says "it might be useful to note that...".

Comment: In fact, based on my comment, we can conclude that the limit does **not** exist if we consider arbitrary (real) $x$-values.  It seems likely you're missing some information from the question, something that says that $x$ is necessarily an integer.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom uhm okay thanks though, then can I ask another question? is euler a good idea, writting radical as 1/2?

Comment: I don't know what "Euler" has to do with rewriting square roots as a 1/2 power.  Are you thinking of L'Hospital?  As in, taking some sort of derivative?

Comment: let me 5 minutes to write what I've tried until now, and also I mention in the first comment that x is from Z (integer)

Answer (score 3):

Note that for any positive integer $x$, we have
$$
x = \sqrt{x^2} \leq \sqrt{x^2 + x + 1} \leq \sqrt{x^2 + 2x + 1} = x+1
$$
Thus, we have
$$
\left\{\sqrt{x^2 + x + 1}\right\} = \sqrt{x^2 + x + 1} - x
$$
we then find
$$
\sqrt{x^2 + x + 1} - x = \frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^2 + x + 1} + x} \to \frac 12
$$
which is the desired limit.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that here $x$ represents a real variable (if $x$ is an integer variable see Omnomnomnom's answer).

For any positive integer $n>1$, let $x_n$ be the positive real number such that $x_n^2+x_n+1=n^2$ (note that $f(x)=x^2+x+1$ is a continuous positive function such that $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=+\infty$).

Then along this sequence:
$$\left\{\sqrt{x_n^2+x_n+1}\right\}=\left\{n\right\}=0.$$

Similarly, for any positive integer $n>1$, let $y_n$ be the positive real number such that $y_n^2+y_n+1=(n+1/2)^2$. Then along this sequence:
$$\left\{\sqrt{y_n^2+y_n+1}\right\}=\left\{n+1/2\right\}=1/2.$$

What may we conclude?

Comment: That the limit does not exist.